# Where is XML spec. of WindowsStoreProxy.xml for CurrentAppSimulator testing

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, in-app-purchase

If I want to test in-app purchases in Windows 8 apps, I need to use **CurrentAppSimulator** with the **WindowsStoreProxy.xml** file defining the current state of the app and all products. The problem is I haven't found anywhere the full definition of the structure, that can be used inside this file, and the IntelliSense/autocomplete is not offering anything.

So the question is where is the **specification of the WindowsStoreProxy.xml file structure**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best available documentation is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator

It includes file structure overview and xsd schema definition.